# Отправка сообщений по userid из бд

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, sqlite3

Всем привет, можете помочь? Пишу на pyTelegramBotAPI, смысл скрипта - пересылать сообщения.
Ошибка:
bot.send_message(chat_info[1], message.text)
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

```
код main.py:
        chat_info = db.get_active_chat(message.chat.id)
        bot.send_message(chat_info[1], message.text)
код бд:
    def get_active_chat(self, chat_id):
        with self.connection:
            chat = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM chats WHERE chat_one = ?", (chat_id,))
            id_chat = 0
            for row in chat:
                id_chat = row[0]
                chat_info = [row[0], row[2]]
            if id_chat == 0:
                chat = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM chats WHERE chat_one = ?", (chat_id,))
                for row in chat:
                    id_chat = row[0]
                    chat_info = [row[0], row[1]]
                if id_chat == 0:
                    return False
                else:
                    return chat_info
            else:
                return chat_info
```

В данный момент бд хранит 3 типа данных - id, user_one, user_two, все они заполнены. Помогите как-то осуществить эту задачу, подсказали что в дазе данных в третьей строке не хватает чего-то...

Comment: Срабатывает `return False`,  вы пытаетесь получить `chat_info[1]` от переменной типа `bool`. Вот и возникает исключение

Comment: Заметил у себя ошибку... Во втором условии 
if id_chat == 0:
                chat = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM chats WHERE chat_one = ?", (chat_id,))
Я написал chat_one = ?, а нужно проверять chat_two...
Всё же спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заметил у себя ошибку... Во втором условии

```
if id_chat == 0: chat = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM chats WHERE chat_one = ?", (chat_id,))
```

Я написал `chat_one = ?`, а нужно проверять `chat_two = ?`... Всё же спасибо за ответ!